# Is Activities Stack cleared when process is being recreated under certain circumstances?

Tags: android, android-activity, process, stack

I've noticed an odd behaviour in an app I'm analyzing and I would like to know if this is by design or it's simply a bug of the platform?

I have a complex application but to simplify my example lets say I have an application with Activity A and B. Now if I run my application and go from A -> B, given that I won't finish Activity A, then I will kill the process (but the app window is still visible in Recent applications) then if I tap the window in recent apps what would happen is:

1) Process is being created
2) Application object is being created
3) Stack is untached (A -> B) and after analyzing it by the framework Activity B is recreated
4) Activity A is "dead" untill I hit the back button

Now the interesting thing happens if I introduce a large singleton instance, lets say an instance of "Dictionary" which can hold many key-value pairs. If that dictionary instance is large enough the above scenario will not happen, meaning that the stack appears to be cleared and my application will follow a typical launch scenario so Activity A is being created instead of Activity B.

Is this a proper behaviour of the Android Framework and if so... why is that proper? I'm interested in the reason and why this occurs.